# Selecting minimal dates, or nulls in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is grossly oversimplified, but:

I have a table, something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [USER] varchar(5), [DATE] date)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [USER], [DATE])
VALUES
    (1, 'A', '2018-10-01'),
    (2, 'A', '2018-09-01'),
    (3, 'A', NULL),
    (4, 'B', '2018-05-03'),
    (5, 'B', '2017-04-01'),
    (6, 'C', NULL)
;
```

And for each user, I wish to retrieve the whole row of details where the `DATE` variable is minimal.

```
SELECT T.USER FROM TABLE1 T
WHERE T.DATE = (SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE T1.USER = T.USER)
```

Works great, however in the instance there is no row with a populated `DATE` field, there will be a row with a `NULL`, like the final row of my table above, which I also wish to select.

So my ideal output in this case is:

```
(2, 'A', '2018-09-01'),
(5, 'B', '2017-04-01'),
(6, 'C', NULL)
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df42b5/6

I think something could be done using an EXCLUDE statement but it gets complex very quickly.

Comment: Is this really SQL Server? SQL Server's quote operator isn't a backtick (`\``) it's brackets (`[]`). This smells like MySQL.

Comment: Apologies. Yes I am in SQL Server, but the code from above was copied from the SQL fiddle.

Comment: [SQL Fiddle can SQL Server](https://imgur.com/a/Oh7VQZT) though.

Comment: The answers here will give you the result you want, but i wanted to explain why what you have isn't working. `NULL` will always have the lowest value in a range. I.e. the `MIN` of the values `1`,`0`,`-1`,`NULL`,`-700` will be `NULL`. The difference is, however, that `NULL = NULL` will always evaluate to "Unknown" (infact `{expression} = NULL` will always be unknown). As a result, this isn't true and thus any relevant rows will not be returned.

Comment: Thanks both!
Larnu, thanks for the explanation. I realised it was to do with checking `NULL = NULL` which didn't seem to return as `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with row_number()

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=afc83b40f4eef4a2538b294b7f26f3d8)

```
    select * from
    (select *, row_number() over(partition by [user] order by [user],case when 
     [date] is null then 0 else 1 end desc,[date]) as rn
     from Table1)x where rn=1
```

Comment: the order by clause seems to be a bit more complicated than necessary

Answer (score 1):

use union and and co-related sub-query with `min()` function

```
     CREATE TABLE Table1 (ID int, usr varchar(50), DATE1 date)
;

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES
    (1, 'A', '2018-10-01'),
    (2, 'A', '2018-09-01'),
    (3, 'A', NULL),
    (4, 'B', '2018-05-03'),
    (5, 'B', '2017-04-01'),
    (6, 'C', NULL)
;



select * from Table1 t  where 
   DATE1= (select min(date1) from Table1 t1 where t1.usr=t.usr
         ) and date1 is not null
           union
select * from Table1 t where date1 is  null
and t.usr not in ( select usr from Table1 where date1 is not null)
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b12855f7595a29c2880c3c06298ec2f)

```
ID  usr     DATE1
2   A   01/09/2018 00:00:00
5   B   01/04/2017 00:00:00
6   C
```

Comment: I don't think this will produce the correct answer, the Null date entry on A will still be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Common Table Expression:

```
;WITH chronology AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [USER] 
            ORDER BY ISNULL([DATE], '2900-01-01') ASC
        ) Idx
    FROM TABLE1
)
SELECT ID, [USER], [DATE]  
FROM chronology
WHERE Idx=1;
```

Using a CTE in this solution simplifies the query improving its readability, maintainability and extensibility. Furthermore, I expect this approach to be optimal in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY and JOIN to output the desired results.

```
select t.Id
    , x.[User]
    , x.[MinDate] as [Date]
from
(select [User]
   , min([Date]) as MinDate
from table1
group by [User]) x
   inner join table1 t on t.[User] = x.[User] and (t.[Date] = x.[MinDate] or x.[MinDate] is null)
```